# Regularization of a Matrix Using a Diagonal Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, regularization

For a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ it is well known that $A + \lambda I$ for suffiecientely large $\lambda >0$ makes $A$ positive definite. The proof is straightforward by looking at the characteristic polynomial. I wonder what happens if we look at a diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ with possibly distinct diagonal elements? Is the  conclusion still valid that $A + \Lambda$ becomes positive definite for large enough $\Lambda$?

Background: I have implemented a code that performs regularization using the former approach. By experimental studies I found that using different values for regularization improves my results. So I was wonderung whether this also backed by theory.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "large enough $\Lambda$"? It makes sense for a number to be large, but what do you mean when you say that the diagonal matrix is large?  Also: for your definition of positive definite, are positive definite matrices necessarily symmetric?

Comment: I understand "large" and "small" for square (symmetric) matrices in terms of Loewner ordering, i.e. $X>Y$ iff $X - Y$ is positive definite. In my case $A$ is symmetric, so yes.

Comment: Well if we have $\Lambda > \lambda I$ (for large enough $\lambda$), then your statement will be true

Comment: "For a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ it is well known that $A + \lambda I$ for suffiecientely large $\lambda >0$ makes $A$ positive definite. *The proof is straightforward by looking at the characteristic polynomial."*  This can't be right.  For an arbitrary n x n matrix, just looking at eigenvalues (or equivalently char poly) is not sufficient to ensure being positive definite.

Comment: @user8675309 not related; but why? the char poly of $A + \lambda I$ becomes $\chi(\xi - \lambda)$ ($\xi$ = eigenvalue of $A$). So all eigenvalues are shiftet to the right. Now just take $\lambda$ large enough to make it positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conclusion is still correct, as 
\begin{align*}
\Lambda&=\text{diag}\left(\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2},\dots,\lambda_{n}\right)\\
&=\lambda_{\text{min}}I+\Xi\\
\Xi&=\text{diag}\left(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{\text{min}},
\lambda_{2}-\lambda_{\text{min}},\dots,\lambda_{n}-\lambda_{\text{min}}\right)\\
\end{align*}
Here $\lambda_{\text{min}}=\min_{1\leq j\leq n}\lambda_{j}$. For large enough $\lambda_{\text{min}}$, we have that $A+\lambda_{\text{min}}I$ is positive definite, that is for any nonzero vector $u$, we have 
\begin{align*}
u^{\top}\left(A+\lambda_{\text{min}}I\right)u>0
\end{align*}

If $u$ is nonzero then

\begin{align*}
u^{\top}\Xi u&=\sum_{j}u_{j}^{2}\left(\lambda_{j}-\lambda_{\text{min}}\right)\geq 0
\end{align*}

using this we have for every nonzero vector $u$

\begin{align*}
u^{\top}\left(A+\Lambda\right)u&=u^{\top}\left(A+\lambda_{\text{min}}I+\Xi\right)u>0
\end{align*}

thus $A+\Lambda$ is guaranteed to be positive definite, provided that the minimum entry of $\Lambda$ is sufficiently large.

Comment: wonderful! very neat proof. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

By definition $A + \lambda I$ is positive definite if, for every vector

$\vec x \ne 0,  \tag 1$

we have

$\vec x^\bot(A + \lambda I) \vec x > 0; \tag{1.5}$

since
$\vec x^\bot(A + \lambda I) \vec x= \vec x^\bot A \vec x + \vec x^\bot (\lambda \vec x) = \vec x^\bot A \vec x + \lambda \vec x^T \vec x, \tag 2$

clearly (1.5) binds for $\lambda > 0$ sufficiently large, since

$\exists M > 0, \; \vert \vec x^\bot A \vec x \vert < M \vec x^\bot \vec x; \tag 3$

we need only choose

$\lambda > M. \tag 4$

If now

$\Lambda = \text{diag}(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n), \tag 5$

then

$\vec x^\bot (A + \Lambda) \vec x = \vec x^\bot A \vec x + \vec x^\bot \Lambda \vec x; \tag 6$

with

$\vec x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)^\bot, \tag 7$

we have

$\Lambda \vec x = (\lambda_1 x_1, \lambda_2 x_2, \ldots, \lambda_n x_n)^\bot, \tag 8$

whence

$\vec x^\bot \Lambda \vec x = \displaystyle \sum_1^n \lambda_i x_i^2; \tag 9$

choosing each $\lambda_i > \lambda$ yields

$\vec x^\bot \Lambda \vec x = \displaystyle \sum_1^n \lambda_i x_i^2 > \lambda \sum_1^n x_i^2 = \lambda \vec x^\bot \vec x, \tag{10}$

from which in light of (1.5) shows that $M + \Lambda$ is positive definite.